# Laravel Nova Set ID manually on Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I want to set my ID manually
since my ID type as string (varchar)

here is my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Master;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UnitOfMeasure extends Model 
{

protected $table = 'unit_of_measures';
public $timestamps = true;
public $incrementing = false;

use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $fillable = array('id','code', 'description', 'scan_input_required');

public function workCenter()
{
    return $this->hasMany(WorkCenter::class,'unit_of_measures_code','code');
}
```

But Nova always hide the ID field.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the request that calls the `creation-fields` endpoint, you will notice that the ID is not even in the list of fields.

The trait ResolvesFields that is used by your Resources are calling a function creationFields to generate the list of fields to display in the front, which is calling **removeNonCreationFields**:

```
/**
 * Remove non-creation fields from the given collection.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $fields
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
protected function removeNonCreationFields(Collection $fields)
{
    return $fields->reject(function ($field) {
        return $field instanceof ListableField ||
               $field instanceof ResourceToolElement ||
               $field->attribute === $this->resource->getKeyName() ||
               $field->attribute === 'ComputedField' ||
               ! $field->showOnCreation;
    });
}
```

And since the field matches this rule:

```
$field->attribute === $this->resource->getKeyName()
```

The ID field is getting removed.

To force the field, you can overwrite that function in your resource:

```
/**
 * Remove non-creation fields from the given collection.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $fields
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
protected function removeNonCreationFields(Collection $fields)
{
    return $fields->reject(function ($field) {
        return $field instanceof ListableField ||
               $field instanceof ResourceToolElement ||
               $field->attribute === 'ComputedField' ||
               ! $field->showOnCreation;
    });
}
```

Comment: you saved my day bro.. thanks. Btw how do you know the creation-fields is Invoke?

Comment: and also for the edit form don't forget to override the removeNonUpdateFields method from ResolveFields.php in resource

Comment: @hendra1 What do you mean how I know the creation-fields is invoke?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself and it looks like Nova has been updated so that you can just add the ID field manually to the resource: `Text::make('ID')` and then you'll have an editable ID field.

Here's the github issue: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/268